# Search for a term in mssql via php depending on an inconstant variable

Tags: php, sql-server, database

Basically, I have a login panel where users can login and what I am trying to do is when they login I want to find out their Authentication ID that has been set in the MSSQL database.

And I want to be able to get the 'AuthID' of the user and make it 'die' (die $result) so that the result is shown in the browser.

At the moment I have this code and with it I am able to get the AuthID but it doesn't get the specific user that is logging in. It gets every single AuthID in the database.

```
<?php

$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
     or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

  $selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
      or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

 $query = "SELECT nAuthID FROM tAccounts";

 $result = mssql_query($query)
     or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());

    while ( $record = mssql_fetch_array($result) )
      {
          die ($record ['nAuthID']);
      }   

    mssql_free_result($result);

    mssql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an user to be able to login to your site and stay logged in you have to save the information as which user he is logged in in some way -> SESSIONS / COOKIES

For login specific data you should use SESSION since their data is stored on the server.
Put `session_start()`at the beginning of every file you want to access any user information.
Then if the user logs in you should save the nEMID or even the nAuthID via `$_SEESION['nID'] = ...your id...;`

On any other site you can check if the user is logged in using `if (isset($_SEESION['nID']))`. Then you can query user-information using your `"SELECT * FROM tAccounts WHERE nEMID=" . $_SEESION['nID']`

Does this helps u a bit?

Comment: Thing is they are not logging into a site but rather a program that has been coded in vb.net.

Comment: You HAVE to get an user_id from somewhere, if you get it once you can save it and read it again but if you don´t get an id i see no nice way to determine which user is currently browsing

Comment: It's saved in the mssql database and the user logs in with their username, so when they login, is it not possible to just get it then.

Comment: okay, with the new code everything should work: where you insert the token `$setToken = mssql_query(...` - there you have to set an session_variable holding the token, later on you can get the token and with that you can query the nEMID from the tTokens-table. then you have your user.
you should set the session_variable putting `session_start();` directly after the opening php-tag. Where you insert the token write additionally `$_SESSION['token'] = $Token;`. Then later you can get the token via `$t = $_SESSION['token'];`.

Comment: But let me tell you that you don´t need to user a token at all in your database-system since you only use it to verify the user, thats exactly what sessions are there for. but first, try to get the above way working, then you can maybe change it up later ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, after connecting to the database, you are directly executing a query "SELECT nAuthID FROM tAccounts" which will fetch all the available nAuthID's from the table.

Your query should authenticate the user after entering the login details in your login form.
So your query in your code should be some thing like below...

```
<?php
$myServer = "Your-PC\SQLExpress";
$myUser = "user";
$myPass = "pass";
$myDB = "Account";

$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
 or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

// $query = "SELECT nAuthID FROM tAccounts";

//Your Query Should be something like this
 $query = "SELECT nAuthID FROM tAccounts WHERE sUsername='username' AND sUserpass= 'yourpassword' ";
$result = mssql_query($query)
 or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());

/*while ( $record = mssql_fetch_array($result) )
  {
      die ($record ['nAuthID']);    
  } */  
if(mssql_num_rows($result)>0){
$record = mssql_fetch_array($result);
$nAuthID = $record ['nAuthID'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['nAuthID'] = $nAuthID;
}else{
    echo 'Login Failed';
}

mssql_free_result($result);

mssql_close($dbhandle);


?>
```

Please make sure that you will be passing the dynamic values to the query. and make a note that you can use the session variable $_SESSION['nAuthID'] to get nAuthID whereever you want to display.

By doing so, you will be getting nAuthID of a particular user who have logged in successfully. Also, you can use else loop if the authentication failed and redirect the user back to login screen.

Hope this clarify your doubt??

Comment: No that doesn't help either. I expanded on my original post. Please read that and see if you can understand it better. Thanks.